# Getting info from syslog.txt

Tags: syslog

I am looking for some cool commands I can use to pull pieces of information out of a syslog.  Mostly using this as a learning experience.  Let's say I have a syslog showing dropped/accepted connections through my firewall.  Say I want to know which source address is being dropped/accepted the most.  Format of the syslog looks something like:

```
Feb 12 09:00:57 kernel: DROP  <4>DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=d8:50:e6:a9:29:e0:00:ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl:mn <1>SRC=12.34.56.78 DST=87.65.43.21 <1>LEN=160 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=43 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP <1>SPT=51413 DPT=1024 LEN=140
```

Preferably a way to find how many unique entries each SRC had in my syslog something that would show each SRC entry from the syslog along with how many times that same event occurred:

```
(source address) | (number of entries)
12.34.56.78 | 25
12.34.56.79 | 13
12.23.34.45 | 6
12.32.32.34 | 1
```

Any cool commands anyone would share?

Comment: This would be more of a learning experience, if you tried to figure things out yourself and came back here with specific questions if you got really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen `grep` ? which searches for string patterns or even `less` to view/page/search interactively at a terminal.

If you want to count lines then `grep` has a count option (-c) another common trick is to pipe output into `wc` (word count) which could also counts lines of output from grep.

Suppose you want to find DROP

```
grep -c DROP syslog | sed -e s'/^.*SRC=//' -e 's/DST=.*$//' |sort -n |uniq -c |sort -nr
```

The counts are at the beginning.

Comment: I am familiar with grep and wc. Yes.  I just couldn't find a way to scan through the entire file and give me a wc on unique entries.  Does that make sense?

Comment: for a better answer, try to be more specific with what you are looking for, maybe provide an example output. tks

Comment: Will do, I'll put something together now. edit: done.